# tensorflow error with in processing algorithm, adversarial debiasing, which is based on tf

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, aif360, fairlearn

I am using adversarial debiasing model from AIF360 which uses TensorFlow. I am getting an error : ValueError: Variable debiased_classifier_20710/classifier_model/W1 already exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True or reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE in VarScope? I am not sure how to handle this error as I am not using TensorFlow directly in my code, I just imported the TensorFlow as base for the model to work. Any leads can be helpful.

Below is the part of code and error I encountered: 
`sess = tf.Session()`
`debiased_model = AdversarialDebiasing(privileged_groups = privileged_groups, unprivileged_groups = unprivileged_groups,  scope_name = f'debiased_classifier_{int(np.random.random()*100000)}',  debias = True, sess = sess)`
`model = debiased_model.fit(train_df)`
`File "python3.10/site-packages/aif360/algorithms/transformer.py", line 27, in wrapper`
`new_dataset = func(self, *args, **kwargs)`
`File "python3.10/site-packages/aif360/algorithms/inprocessing/adversarial_debiasing.py", line 152, in fit`
`self.pred_labels, pred_logits = self._classifier_model(self.features_ph, self.features_dim,  self.keep_prob)`
`File "python3.10/site-packages/aif360/algorithms/inprocessing/adversarial_debiasing.py", line  84, in _classifier_model`
`W1 = tf.get_variable('W1', [features_dim, self.classifier_num_hidden_units],`
`File "python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 1616, in  get_variable`
`return get_variable_scope().get_variable(`
`File "python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 1326, in  get_variable`
`return var_store.get_variable(`
`File "python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 582, in  get_variable`
`return _true_getter(`
`File "python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 535, in  _true_getter`
`return self._get_single_variable(`
`File "python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 891, in  _get_single_variable`
`raise ValueError(err_msg)`
`ValueError: Variable debiased_classifier_20710/classifier_model/W1 already exists, disallowed.  Did you mean to set reuse=True or reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE in VarScope?`

I tried researching the ways I can handle this but none of the ways shows to handle this error when  TensorFlow is being used at backend by a model.